# Magento 2 - How to disable the wishlist for guests only?

Tags: magento2, products, customer-account, wishlist, guest-checkout

On anywhere it may appear including product grids and pdp's.

I want to disable the Wishlist module including hiding all links in the menues (i.e. Dashboard, Top Navigation).

Is there an easy way to do this?

I know that i can do this: `php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Wishlist`
to disable it completely but that's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: where you can to distable on product page or on category page

Comment: I'm not sure, that's the question at hand sir.